# Highlight all rows equal to value in cell foobar

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am trying to code this procedure to highlight all rows of which have a value of "N" in their respective row within Column N

I am not too familiar with coding VBA formatting and I cannot get this procedure to function

```
Sub highlight_new_pos()

Dim rng As Range, lCount As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim cell As Object

With ActiveSheet    'set this worksheet properly!
    LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell In .Range("N2:N" & LastRow)
        If cell = "N" Then
            With Selection.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 65535
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With

    Next cell
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: [Conditional Formatting](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Use-a-formula-to-apply-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) with a native worksheet formula like `=$N1="N"` is a better solution.

Comment: @pnuts - tbh, I never use any of the preformed rules. I prefer to supply formulas that work.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are looping through the cells, but you're still changing the color of the initial selection (not of the cell in the loop). Adjust as follows:

```
Sub highlight_new_pos()

Dim rng As Range, lCount As Long, LastRow As Long
Dim cell As Object

With ActiveSheet    'set this worksheet properly!
    LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each cell In .Range("N2:N" & LastRow)
        If cell = "N" Then
            With cell.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 65535
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End if
    Next cell
End With


End Sub
```

If you want the entire row, change `cell.Interior` to `cell.entirerow.Interior`

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Sub highlight_new_pos()
    Dim cel As Object

    With ActiveSheet
        For Each cel In .Range("N2:N" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row)
            If UCase(cel.Value2) = "N" Then cel.Interior.Color = 65535
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

---

This will be faster if you have a lot of rows:

```
Sub highlight_new_pos1()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet
        With .Range("N1:N" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="N"
            .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 14, .Columns.Count).Interior.Color = 65535
            .AutoFilter
        End With
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks @pnuts: it is better, and I updated it (wasn't sure about data and if the entire row needs to be highlighted or not)